# Preventing 'ALL' Type in Mysql Explain SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin, explain

I am trying to understand Mysql Explain and I read the the Type "ALL" is the worst for performance. I just wrote a very simple sql with one left join

```
SELECT * FROM production_plan_header pph LEFT JOIN production_plan_details ppd ON ppd.ppd_header_id = pph.pph_id WHERE pph.pph_id =1
```

If I use EXPLAIN on this I get the following.

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len      ref    rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE          pph     const   PRIMARY         PRIMARY     4            const  1   
1   SIMPLE          ppd     ALL     ppd_header_id   NULL        NULL         NULL   7
```

As you can see the production_plan_details has a type "ALL". The rows show the total number of the rows in the table (7). The ppd_header_id  column is indexed. Is there a way to prevent this "ALL" from my sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly, but if you want to remove rows having Type = "ALL", in that case you can write your query like following.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   production_plan_header pph 
       LEFT JOIN production_plan_details ppd 
              ON ppd.ppd_header_id = pph.pph_id 
WHERE  pph.pph_id = 1 
       AND ppd.type <> "ALL"
```

Comment: Thanks but my question was can I prevent a "ALL" type from a simple sql like "SELECT * FROM production_plan_header pph LEFT JOIN production_plan_details ppd ON ppd.ppd_header_id = pph.pph_id WHERE pph.pph_id =1". I read that using indexes it is possible. Just learning to write efficient sqls. thanks